# Dereferencing possible null pointer warning with mysql PrepareStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, nullpointerexception, nullreferenceexception

I am still new to Java, although I have to say, I am starting to get the hang of it and it is very cool.  Anyway, in my Netbeans IDE, I am getting the warning `Dereferencing possible null pointer`.  Please see a snapshot of the code here.  You can see the yellow line underlining the null-pointer warning.

Here is the plain text

```
    /*
     * Establish Connection to MySQL
     */
    Connection conn;
    conn = MySQLConnectionClass.getCurrentConnection();
    if (conn == null){
      System.out.println("MySQL not connected!");
    }

    /*
    * get the change in price-nav/price
    */
    double nav_change;
    float first_close = 0;
    float first_nav_close = 0;
    float last_nav_close = 0;
    String sym = "";
    try{
        try (PreparedStatement get_p = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT close, symbol FROM test.cef_daily_data where symbol = (select symbol from cef_nav_real_time_trading_watch_list where id = ?) order by date desc limit 6,1;")) {
            get_p.setInt(1,id);
            ResultSet price = get_p.executeQuery();
            try{
                price.next();
                first_close = price.getFloat(1);
                sym = price.getString(2);
                price.close();
            }catch (SQLException e){

            }
        }
```

Here is the image showing the warning.

[image]

I found a good beginner explaination about dereferencing null pointers [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/EXP01-J.+Never+dereference+null+pointers).

I figured maybe the `PreparedStatement` variable: `get_p` had a possibility of being `null`, so I tried putting a line after to check to make sure `get_p` is not `null`, but this didn't make the warning go away.

So I am not just trying to make this warning go away, I am also trying to learn about what the problem is to improve my Java skills.  Thanks for any help!

**Update**

The problem was the `conn` variable had a possibility of being `null`.  I added a `return` line like this that fixed the problem:

```
/*
 * Establish Connection to MySQL
 */
Connection conn;
conn = MySQLConnectionClass.getCurrentConnection();
if (conn == null){
  System.out.println("MySQL not connected!");
  return;
}
```

Comment: could you post your code as plain text?

Comment: I am pretty sure that your resultset is null. First of all try to run your query in your dbms.

Comment: the result set is not null, at least for this query.  The code all works without any errors, it is just this warning about possibly dereferencing the a null value.  (I think)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (conn == null){
  System.out.println("MySQL not connected!");
}
```

...will just print a message and go on referencing the null pointer in the following rows anyway (the prepareStatement call is the following use of it). You may want to add a `return` or some kind of error handling bypassing the actual query if there is no connection.

Comment: Yes!! I added a `return` after the `System.out.println("MySQL not connected!");` and this fixed the warning.  Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of `conn = MySQLConnectionClass.getCurrentConnection();`. 
You have not initialized `conn`. It gets initialized with method's return value.

It might happen that `Null` gets returned from the method. So, Netbeans IDE is showing warning.

Also,

```
if (conn == null){
  System.out.println("MySQL not connected!");
}
```

has no meaning, It will just print message on console and continue to execute next lines.